# Meteor Framework on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor

I have an application developed in Meteor Framework.
We are planning to move it to AWS withmulti AZ deployment
need Master Slave configuration for the Mongo DB
My question is how to achieve this, i believe mongo db comes bundled in with the Framework itself, 
never worked on it so any help will be appriciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Mongo is bundled into the development environment, but not the server.

It is normal to host the database either on a different server of your own, or using a database service (there are many around, such as compose.io, Mongolab etc) So Mongo can be set up for load balancing and scaling independently of the app itself.